# Getting date from a string without time in php

Tags: php, symfony-3.2

I have to convert a string input to date "1990/07/22" to 22/07/1990 as date,My function is as follows as:

```
public function($date){
    $date_format_sec = strtotime($date);
    $date_of_birth = new \DateTime('@'.$date_format_sec);
}
```

It uploads date as 21/07/1990 since I didn't give time.How to get the exact date given as same as input.

Comment: You don't need to use strtotime($date) if $date is a valid date string, you can pass this on the constructor of DateTime and then format it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format your date with php

```
$formatedDate = $date_of_birth->format('d-m-Y');
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
    $input = '1990/07/22';
    $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d', $input)->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

As I said, you don't need to use strtotime, if the $date string is a valid date, the class DateTime will read it. After that you can use format.

In this example I set the format to be always the one you expect, while you can put any other format accepted by it.

```
public function getMyDate($date, $format = 'd/m/Y') {
    $date_of_birth = new \DateTime($date);

    return $date_of_birth->format($format);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    public function formatDate($date) {return date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));}
```

Comment: he's using a DateTime object... why would you go to strtotime if you have the object?

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should always explain how the problem has been solved and what the code does.